# VS Code launch.json attach to iexplore

Tags: visual-studio-code, office-js

I would like to debug my office-js application (with angular2) within VS-Code.
My launch.json is:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 4200,
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/*.js"
            ]
        }
```

Currently I'm using Atom Editor with angular cli and "ng serve" command and VS Community Edition 2017 as debugger. It works with "Attach to Process" (iexplore) and I'm able to debug my Word AddIn.

For simplification I tried to move to VS-Code which -for my understanding- supports inline debugging.

In launch.json, "type" could be "node", "chrome", "edge", "firefox" but I didn't found iexplore which I would need in my opinion.

Thank you in advance for sharing your expierences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of debuggers in the [extension marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VSCode&category=Debuggers&sortBy=Downloads) but I'm not aware of one for Internet Explorer.